Evaluating the Jacobi Determinant of Cartesian-Spherical Transformation in n-dimensions
I am trying to evaluate the volume of a 4-dimensional (or even n-dimensional) sphere as an exercise, and I thought of trying to derive the formula $V = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ in 3-dimensions first. In order to do so, I would need to use spherical coordinates. The equation for a hemisphere is $z = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - y^2}$. The Cartesian-spherical tranformation is given by function $\textbf{F}: \textbf{R}^3 \rightarrow \textbf{R}^+ × [0, π) × [0, 2π) $.
The Jacobian of this transformation is given by
$$\det(\textbf{J}_\textbf{F} (x, y, z)) = \left|
  {\begin{array}{cc}
   \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z}\\
   \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}\\
  \end{array} } \right|
$$
I struggle with taking the partial derivatives of $\varphi$ with respect to $y$ since it depends on the sign of $y$. Is there any other way to approach this problem or evaluate the partial derivative? Any suggestions are appreciated.

The way you do an integral in spherical coordinates goes the other way, computing the Jacobian of $F^{-1}$, which is easier; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates. There are also other ways to calculate the volume of an $n$-ball: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Proofs

And may I ask how computing the Jacobian of inverse $\mathbf{F}$ will help us evaluate the integral?

Always use the Jaobian of the map spherical to cartesian euclidean coordinates
$$ J =\frac{\partial(x_1,\dots,\ x_n)}{\partial (r,\phi,\theta_1,\dots,\theta_{n-2})}$$ constructed as a nested ladder of n-spheres
$$X_2\ = \ r(\cos \phi, \sin \phi), \quad  X_{n+1} = (  \cos \theta_{n-2},\ \sin \theta_{n-2} \ X_n,)$$
On any n-sphere $\phi$ is the unique angle on the equatorial greatest circle ranging in $(0,2 \pi)$, while  all other angles $\theta_k$ are polar angles ranging in $(0,\pi)$.
The transformation for $\phi$ in any dimension is always

$$\frac{y}{x} \ = \
 \cases{{ \tan \phi}  {\quad  x>0 ,|\phi|<\frac{\pi}{2}}\\
       { -\tan (\pi-\phi)} {\quad x < 0, |\phi|>\frac{\pi}{2}} }$$
The continuous inverse of this map is the called $\phi=\text{actan2(x,y)}$ or simply $$\phi=\tan^{-1}(x,y)$$ with
$$d\phi \ =   \frac{-y\  dx + x \ dy}{x^2+y^2}$$
and
$$d \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\left(\cos \tan^{-1}(x,y), \sin \tan^{-1}(x,y)\right) =(dx,dy) \right)$$
The fact that the sphere manifold is the product of a full circle with a bundle of real intervals for all the meridians between the two poles of the axis in spherical coordinates makes it inevitable that two overlapping covering maps of the unit circle are necessary to define differentiable maps to $\mathbb R^{n-1}$
